# When do I capitalize?

Tags: science

Do I capitalize the c and s in Cognitive science when referring to the career? What about the n in Neuroscience, or Neurobiolgy. And the P in Psychology?

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not capitalize those subject areas because none of them are proper nouns (in other word, they are not the titles of specific entities); they are all generic designations.

It would be different if you were talking about something like a course being offered by a particular educational institution. For example:

> "I'm taking Cognitive Neuroscience this semester".

Some people are tempted to capitalize words simply because they feel they are especially significant. However, it is less confusing for their readers (and less distracting) if they do not capitalize words that are not proper nouns or proper names.